# Splitting a string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string which is `####I_AM_SAM,`. What I want is to use only the text part. So I was trying to use `split` and split it like this: `line = f.readline().split(',' ,'    ')` where `f.readline()` reads this "    I_AM_SAM,". I expected line[0] to fetch the text, but this gives me an error. Note that there are 4 spaces before the text "I_AM_SAM". I have represented the space bar with a "#" symbol.

```
line = f.readline().split(',' ,'    ')
```

> TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: I have edited my question there are 4 spaces before `I_AM_SAM,` . I want to extract I_AM_SAM

Answer (score 2):

just use `strip()`:

```
In [34]: strs="    I_AM_SAM,"

In [35]: strs.strip(" ,") # pass a space " "and "," to strip
Out[35]: 'I_AM_SAM'
```

Comment: for me strs="####I_AM_SAM," and and not strs="I_AM_SAM," wher `#` represent spacebar

Answer (score 2):

```
line = f.readline().split(',' ,'    ')
  TypeError: an integer is required
```

is caused by the second argument to `split`, it must be an integer:

> S.split([sep[, maxsplit]]) -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the words in S, using sep as the delimiter string. 
>   If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done. If sep is not
>   specified or is None, any whitespace string is a separator and empty
>   strings are\nremoved from the result.

In your case you need `line = f.readline().split(',')[0]`. Also, consider using [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Answer (score 0):

Split takes two arguments, the first being the separator to split on, the second the maximum number of splits it does. So this code:

```
'Hello there, this is a line'.split (' ', 2)
```

will result in three strings: 'Hello', 'there,' and 'this is a line'.

You want to omit the second argument, or make it 1 (not sure, your description is not clear enough). If you want more than one character to split on, you need multiple calls to split.

If this isn't the answer you expected, please make the question more clear: what do you expect to get? What is the reason you put the second argument in split? And one more thing: if that space in the literal string is a tab, please write it as \t for readability.